# Thunderbird not showing new folders in the left bar

Tags: thunderbird

I have a sieve script creating new folders on the server side as needed, and automatically subscribing clients to them.

The issue is for some reason Thunderbird doesn't display it in the left bar until I fold and un-fold the parent.

Is there a trick or an addon to get thunderbird to refresh the left bar automatically when getting a new email? I'm using thunderbird 83, and I tried ticking / unticking everything I found including the `mail.check_all_imap_folders_for_new` option in the config editor without any success.

The folder does get subscribed, the left bar just doesn't refresh automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The setting you use is outdated and was replaced in Thunderbird 5 by a new option:

> Thunderbird used to support setting
> `mail.check_all_imap_folders_for_new` to true to make it check every
> remote folder for new mail. The downside was there is no way to
> exclude a specific folder (such as a junk mail folder). However, that
> setting was replaced in version 5.0 with server-specific ones. Set
> `mail.server.default.check_all_folders_for_new` to true instead to make
> it effective for all accounts using the Config Editor.
> [Quote from "Checking for new messages in other folders - Thunderbird"](http://kb.mozillazine.org/How_do_I_check_for_new_messages_in_other_folders)

```
# Old setting (deprecated, do not use it):
mail.check_all_imap_folders_for_new

# "New" setting (since TB 5): 
mail.server.default.check_all_folders_for_new
```

Comment: Hey, sorry that's actually the one I used. I must have c/c the wrong thing but I do have the "new" one set to true, which doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: @Ulrar Have you also set the property `mail.imap.use_status_for_biff` to true as the linked page suggests in case of problems?

Comment: That setting is "true" by default for me, so I didn't touch it

Answer (score 0):

When did it stop working?

If you can [get a regression range](https://mozilla.github.io/mozregression/), please [file a bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Thunderbird)

Comment: This is a new setup, I don't know that it ever worked. I worked around it by having Dovecot create a virtual folder for unread messages, that way I can see new messages even if thunderbird doesn't pick up the folder